# Specify format of date being read in by pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I am using pandas to read in multiple sets of data from csv files. Is there any way to specify the date format of data being read in with read_csv?

For example I have one data file that has a date time column with the following format:

```
d/m/y h:mm
```

and another with the following format:

```
yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:ss
```

I want to read in these files and then match the second date format. I can then use to_datetime to make sure that the column format as a datetime format and can be used as a pandas index. Is there a way to specify either the incoming format or change the outgoing format for each one with to_datetime or read_csv? The end goal is to concat these different dataframes so that the datetime index will merge.

Comment: provide a `date_parser` argument?

Comment: would you be able to elaborate on date_parser argument? I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: I'm saying, just use `to_datetime`, it should understand both, although, if you know ahead of time the format, you should specify the format in either `to_datetime` or when the csv is read, providing a `date_parser` argument. Have you checked the documentaiton? It is all explained there...

Comment: I see what you're saying. The documentation wasn't too clear to me on how to use that argument. I tried using the "datefirst" argument but I'm still not too clear on if it is reading in or putting out the date as day first. What I mean is that I've used "dayfirst" and been given the correct sequence but is the day defined first as well in the output.

would you be able to give me a simple string you would use for the date_parser argument?

Comment: Maybe it's better to just load them as strings, i.e. don't parse dates on `pd.read_csv`, then just use [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) and pass a `format` argument

Answer (score 0):

I create a csv file named: **table.csv** separated by `;`

```
date;numbers
1/1/19 9:9;1
25/12/18 11:11;2
;
date;numbers
2019-01-02 09:09:09;3
2018-12-26 11:11:11;4
```

Hope this code helps you understand how `date_parser` dates in diferent [formats](http://strftime.org/):

```
import pandas as pd

fin = 'table.csv'

# NORMAL
dfA = pd.read_csv(fin, header=0, sep=';', nrows=2)
dfB = pd.read_csv(fin, header=4, sep=';', nrows=2)
dfN = pd.concat([dfA,dfB], ignore_index=True)

# PARSING DATE for each DataFrame with the
# date_parser
dfA = pd.read_csv(fin, header=0, sep=';', nrows=2, 
    parse_dates=['date'], 
    date_parser=lambda x: pd.datetime.strptime(x, '%d/%m/%y %H:%M'))

dfB = pd.read_csv(fin, header=4, sep=';', nrows=2, 
    parse_dates=['date'], 
    date_parser=lambda x: pd.datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))

dfP = pd.concat([dfA,dfB], ignore_index=True)


print("normal", dfN['date'].dtype)
print("parser", dfP['date'].dtype)
print()
print(dfN)
print()
print(dfP)
```